# No longer receiving mails/able to send mails

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, iptables

I am unable to receive new mails (the connection between the client and the server runs fine, but the server is not getting new mails) I'm also unable to send new mails.

I was setting up bandwith monitoring in Webmin the other day and had to install iptables and such. Since I set iptables to allow any traffic, and I had no problems with the apache webserver whatsoever, I thought everything was fine.

Ofcourse I just now noticed I haven't received any new mail today. And I'm unable to send any. I already removed iptables and its settings, but no luck.

I am seeing lots of this in the mail log:

```
Oct 25 22:46:59 KIP-DU-VPS imapd: LOGIN, user=zer, ip=[::ffff:10.10.0.173], port=[35740], protocol=IMAP
Oct 25 22:46:59 KIP-DU-VPS imapd: LOGOUT, user=zer, ip=[::ffff:10.10.0.173], headers=0, body=0, rcvd=79, sent=2249, time=0
Oct 25 22:47:28 KIP-DU-VPS postfix/tlsmgr[4814]: fatal: open database /var/lib/postfix/smtpd_scache.db: Invalid argument
Oct 25 22:47:29 KIP-DU-VPS postfix/master[4011]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/tlsmgr pid 4814 exit status 1
Oct 25 22:47:29 KIP-DU-VPS postfix/master[4011]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/tlsmgr: bad command startup -- throttling
Oct 25 22:47:59 KIP-DU-VPS imapd: Connection, ip=[::ffff:10.10.0.173]
Oct 25 22:47:59 KIP-DU-VPS imapd: LOGIN, user=zer, ip=[::ffff:10.10.0.173], port=[35752], protocol=IMAP
Oct 25 22:47:59 KIP-DU-VPS imapd: LOGOUT, user=zer, ip=[::ffff:10.10.0.173], headers=0, body=0, rcvd=79, sent=2249, time=0
Oct 25 22:48:29 KIP-DU-VPS postfix/tlsmgr[4968]: fatal: open database /var/lib/postfix/smtpd_scache.db: Invalid argument
Oct 25 22:48:30 KIP-DU-VPS postfix/master[4011]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/tlsmgr pid 4968 exit status 1
Oct 25 22:48:30 KIP-DU-VPS postfix/master[4011]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/tlsmgr: bad command startup -- throttlin
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, the `/var/lib/postfix/smtpd_scache.db` file got corrupted (0 byte large)

Removing it fixed everything.